# Pulling dbname from web.config using powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, web-config

Found one part of my answer here, [Get dbname from multiple web.config files with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053595/get-dbname-from-multiple-web-config-files-with-powershell/57187700#57187700)

But need it to recurse through the IIS Sites and all the Web Apps inside those 'Sites'.  I have multiple IIS 'Sites' with multiple Web Apps in each 'Site' need to check each ones web.config file and pull the db used. Cant figure out how to recurse the code in the link above.

```
    #Code from link above.

Import-Module WebAdministration

Get-WebApplication | 
ForEach-Object {

$webConfigFile = [xml](Get-Content "$($_.PhysicalPath)\Web.config")
Write-Host "Web Application: $($_.path)"
foreach($connString in $webConfigFile.configuration.connectionStrings.add)
{
  Write-Host "Connection String $($connString.name): $($connString.connectionString)"
  $dbRegex = "((Initial\sCatalog)|((Database)))\s*=(?<ic>[a-z\s0-9]+?);"
  $found = $connString.connectionString -match $dbRegex
  if ($found)
  {
   Write-Host "Database: $($Matches["ic"])"
  }

}
Write-Host " "
}
```

Would like this to output the database name of each web.config file for each IIS Site and for each Web App in the IIS Site. Currently this only looks at the first web app in a IIS Site, and doesnt look at any others in the IIS Site, also doenst look to see if the IIS Site's web.config has a connection string to a DB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for you, from your reference I have changed looping mechanism not the actual logic to get the db name.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

Get-Website | % {

    $AppList = Get-WebApplication -Site $_.Name 
    foreach ( $app in $AppList )
    {
        $app.PhysicalPath
        $webConfigFile = [xml](Get-Content "$($app.PhysicalPath)\Web.config")

        # NEED TO CHECK WEATHER THE $webConfigFile  FILE EXIST OR NOT

        Write-Host "Web Application: $($_.path)"
        foreach($connString in $webConfigFile.configuration.connectionStrings.add)
        {
            Write-Host "Connection String $($connString.name): $($connString.connectionString)"
            $dbRegex = "((Initial\sCatalog)|((Database)))\s*=(?<ic>[a-z\s0-9]+?);"
            $found = $connString.connectionString -match $dbRegex
            if ($found)
            {
                Write-Host "Database: $($Matches["ic"])"
            }
        }

    } # END OF INNER FOR EACH LOOP

} # END OF OUTER FOR EACH LOOP
```

Comment: Niraj; Is there a way to also pull the details of the websites web.config? This will pull the info for all the websites web applications, but the root of the web site is not grabbed.  To get the full list of DB used, would need the WebSites root web.config and all its web apps.

Thank you for  your help on this.

Comment: This also seems to be skipping WebApps, it grabs the first one in a Site and moves onto next site.
So for example I have 3 Websites, each with 3 webapps, the output will only show 3 lines of output, the first webapp for each Website, where it should show 9 lines, a line for each Web app , this case 3, for each Website, this case 3. 3*3=9

Comment: foreach ( $app in $AppList ) this line is loop for each webapp within the site.. Try to print the list of webapps so you can come to know whats going on in the loop..

Comment: I have tested with 2 sites and 2 webapp for each, it works for me because this is the part of my automation, so this will also work for you. May be this need some little change